# Simple Enum with values in Dart

Tags: dart, enums

Currently i am using freezed to implement enum, but i wanted to have more than one values like labels, id etc.

```dart
import 'package:freezed_annotation/freezed_annotation.dart';

enum OvertimeType {
  @JsonValue(0)
  unknown,

  @JsonValue(1)
  normalOt,

  @JsonValue(2)
  earlyOt,

  @JsonValue(3)
  compensatoryTimeOff,

  @JsonValue(4)
  earlyCTO,

  @JsonValue(5)
  restDayOrHolidayCTO,
}
```

My entity class content

```dart
class OvertimeTypeInfo {
  final OvertimeType type;
  final String name;
  final String description;

  OvertimeTypeInfo(this.type, this.name, this.description);
}
```

More values associated with the enum OvertimeType

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would simply use extension for this enum so that i could map other values needed:

```
extension CertificateOfAttendanceHelper on OvertimeType {

  static final _values = [
    _OvertimeTypeInfo(OvertimeType.normalOT, 'Name', 'Description for normalOT'),
    _OvertimeTypeInfo(OvertimeType.earlyOT, 'Name', 'Description for earlyOT'),
    _OvertimeTypeInfo(OvertimeType.normalCTO, 'Name', 'Description for normalCTO'),
    _OvertimeTypeInfo(OvertimeType.earlyCTO, 'Name', 'Description for earlyCTO'),
    _OvertimeTypeInfo(OvertimeType.restDayOrHolidayCTO, 'Name', 'Description for restDayOrHolidayCTO'),
  ];

  String get name => _values[index].name;
  String get description => _values[index].description;

  OvertimeType get mode => _values[index].type;
}

class _OvertimeTypeInfo {
  final OvertimeType type;
  final String name;
  final String description;

  _OvertimeTypeInfo(this.type, this.name, this.description);
}
```

Comment: This could be the workaround worked for me so far, i'll try it furthermore :)

Answer (score 1):

You could just use properties on the enum as such:

```
enum OvertimeType {
  unknown('Unknown', 'Description of unknown'),
  normalOt('Normal overtime', 'Description of normal');

  const OvertimeType(this.label, this.description);

  final String label;
  final String description;
}
```

I'm curious on what you use the freezed package for with regards to the enum. It seems like you just use json serializer annotations?

Example on [DartPad](https://dartpad.dev/?id=774397bd118227c28dcb3ba38bd93745).

Comment: so it would be better not to use freeze in this case, i suppose?

Comment: this is more readable and straight forward, but unfortunately we have constraints on using sdk: ">=2.14.0....". Thank you anyway :)

Comment: This requires the 'enhanced-enums' language feature to be enabled.  Try updating your pubspec.yaml to set the minimum SDK constraint to 2.17.0 or higher, and running 'pub get'.

Comment: Yeah. I can obviously not say that you should upgrade your constraints because I don't know why you have those constraints. But anyway, you _should_ :) :) The required SDK isn't that new. It is almost one year old... It was released 11 May 2022. I don't thing there are any breaking changes between 2.14 and 2.17...

Comment: I see no reason why you use freezed. You could just use json_serializable, and I don't think you even need to annotate the enum if you don't have any particular reason to.